# What is the proper handling of NULL bytes found in HTML5?

Tags: html, dom, html-parsing

What does the HTML5 specification state about the proper behavior of an HTML/DOM parser, should it ever encounter a NULL byte character within that HTML file?

Comment: What do you mean by a NULL byte? `%00`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the U+0000 NULL character, then in most cases, the spec requires conforming HTML parsers to replace that with a U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER. In some cases, the spec requires it to just be ignored.

But for HTML parsers that implement error reporting, the spec requires the parser to report an [*unexpected-null-character*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parse-error-unexpected-null-character) error. (This is one of the kinds of errors the spec refers to with the term [*parse error*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parse-errors), but despite what you might assume from that name, it’s not a fatal error that causes parsing to stop—instead in non-error-reporting parsers, that “error” is essentially just a no-op.)

Anyway, if you want to know what the spec requires for handling NULL in particular cases, you can in your browser do a find-in-page search for *U+0000 NULL* in the following section of the spec:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing

When you do that, you’ll come across a couple of notes that are relevant:

> The handling of U+0000 NULL characters varies based on where the characters are found and happens at the later stages of the parsing.
>   …
>   In general, such code points are either completely ignored or, for security reasons, replaced with a U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.